# Always show the selected option in a select of size=3 in the middle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a select with the size of 3.
In this select there are about 5 options.
Now i want to have a cool scrolling effect of these options. Therefore i want the selected option to be be in the middle of the 3 shown options.
So above the selected option should be one option, and under it too. It should look something like this. (I made this manually)

[image]

In the end it should look like a gambling machiene.

[image]

The sevens shall be the selected option, and there is one option above (if there is an option in the html above) and one under it.

Is this just possible with js / jquery, or is there any way to realize this with css only?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it in CSS with a normal `<select>`, but you might be able to do it if you replace it with an HTML list.

Comment: But it should be pretty easy with jQuery.